# Want to use Forloop.index

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

```
 {% for block in section.blocks %}
                            {% assign innerloops = forloop.index %}
                            <a href="">
                                <img src="{{ block.settings.image-menu1 | img_url:"800x" }}" alt="">
                                <p></p>
                            </a>
                          <a href="">
                                <img src="{{ block.settings.image-menu2 | img_url:"800x" }}" alt="">
                                <p></p>
                            </a>
                            {% endfor %}
```

Instead of block.settings.image-menu1 i want to use block.settings.image-menu{{}forloop.index}

Comment: `forloop.index` increase after the loop completed, so it remians same into one round for both images.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign a variable a value and use it.

index is a number. convert it to string by using `append: ""`

```
{% for block in section.blocks %}
  {% assign index = forloop.index | append: "" %}
  {% assign url = "image-menu" | append: index %}
  <a href="">
    <img src="{{ block.settings.url | img_url:"800x" }}" alt="">
    <p></p>
  </a>
{% endfor %}
```